# Como configurar un campo reCAPTCHA

Tags: php

es la primera vez que intento integrar un campo reCAPTCHA en mi proyecto, ya di de alta mi host ya obtuve mi site_key la coloque dentro de mi formulario, pero al momento de mandar el formulario no pasa nada y lo manda sin hacer el check, alguien me podría ayudar a saber que paso me falto.

Les dejo mi código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
 <form class="form-group" method="POST" action="{{URL::to('guardar-registro')}}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="nombre"   id="nombre"   placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="telefono" id="telefono" maxlength="10" placeholder="Teléfono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="email" id="email"   placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lcbyk8Lclrmrew"></div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Saludos y agradezco por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene que validar tu formulario antes de hacer el submit.
Yo lo hago de esta forma:

**Html**

```
<form method="POST" id="form_contacto" onsubmit="return false;">
                        <p>  
                            <label> Nombre: (*)</label>
                            <input name="name" type="text" autocomplete="off" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="Requerido"> 
                        </p>
                        <div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="{poner tu key site}"></div>
                        <button type="button" onclick="enviar_correo()" class="btn bg-probelleza text-white float-right"><i id="loader"></i> Enviar</button>
                    </form>
```

**JS**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-UdIMMlVx0HEynClOIFSyOrPggomfhBKJE28LKl8yR3ghkgugPnG6iLfRfHwushZl1MOPSY6TsuBDGPK2X4zYKg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

<script>
function enviar_correo(){
    var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if ($("#form_contacto").valid()) {
        if(response.length == 0){ 
            alert('tiene que validar el captcha');
            evt.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }else{
            $.ajax({                  
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('send_contacto') }}",
                data: $("#form_contacto").serialize(), 
                })
                .done(function (response) {
                    alert('mensaje enviado');
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Puedes hacerlo de esa forma ó puedes [leer este post](https://html.form.guide/snippets/google-recaptcha-javascript-validation/) y hacerlo con PHP con cURL.

Comment: Hola @José Vásquez muchas gracias por tu comentario, me fue de gran utilidad, ya que como me mencionas me faltaba validar el campo con el Script como me lo compartiste, te agradezco mucho en verdad.

Comment: De nada @Bahamut85 es un gusto ayudar :)